# How to read specific line number of text file without looping ReadLine()?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

Is there a class that lets you read lines by line number in C#?

I know about StreamReader and TextFieldParser but AFAIK those don't have this functionality. For example, if I know that line number 34572 in my text file contains certain data, it would be nice to not have to call `StreamReader.ReadLine()` 34572 times.

Comment: Nope! You've to skip `34571` lines.

Comment: You could `ReadToEnd()`, `Split()` by `Environment.NewLine` and then access the resulting array by index.

Comment: @Sean That's got to be the worst way to go about it. Read all the file at once into memory just to get to a given line? That's crazy overkill.

Comment: @Sean How would that be materially different from reading line by line?

Comment: @Luaan True, depends how far through the file the particular line is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's not but you would also have any other lines you needed. If you were really intent on keeping memory usage to a minimum your answer would be better and, depending on the remaining contents of the file, slightly faster.

Comment: @Sean I think the real issue is that asker wants to perform random access seeking on a text file. Nuances over how to most efficiently find line i are a second order effect. The big point is that you cannot do random access.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah I didn't mean to mislead or imply that's not the case. Your answer perfectly explains why this is not in file I/O implementations.

Comment: @AVD to read 34572 lines using StreamReader you still have to call ReadLine() a total of 34572 times though :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless the file has a precise and pre-determined format, for instance with every line having the same length, there is no way to seek within a text file.

In order to find the i<sup>th</sup> line, you must find the first i-1 line ends. And if you do not know anything about where those line ends could be, it follows that you must read the entire file up until the i<sup>th</sup> line.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a problem of C# - this is a problem of line terminators. There's no way to skip to the 34572 line, because you don't know when it starts - the only thing you know is that it starts after you find 34571 `\r\n`s. If you need this functionality, you don't want to be using text files at all :)

A simple (but still slow) way would be to use `File.ReadLines(...)`:

```
var line = File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(34571).FirstOrDefault();
```

The best way, however, would be to know the actual byte offset of the line. If you remember the offset instead of the line number, you can simply seek in the stream and avoid reading the unnecessary data. Then you'd just continue reading the line as usual:

```
streamReader.BaseStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
```

This is useful if the file is append-only (e.g. a log file) and you can afford to remember bookmarks. It will only work if the file isn't modified *in front of* the bookmark, though.

All in all, there are three options:

- Add indexing - have a table that contains all (or some) of the line-start offsets
- Have a fixed line length - this allows you to seek predictably without an index; however, this will not work well with unicode, so it's pretty much useless these days
- Parse the file - this pretty much amounts to reading the file line by line, the only optimisation being that you don't actually need to allocate the strings - a simple reusable `byte` buffer would do.

There's a reason why text formats aren't preferred when performance is important - when you work with user-editable general text formats, the third option is the only option. Thus, reading from a JSON, XML, text log file etc. will always mean reading up to at least the line you want.

Comment: Is this going to put the entire file in the memory? Like, 34572+ lines of unknown size into memory? And he OP also mentioned that he doesn't want to read all lines...

Comment: @BrunoLM No, it's going to iterate over the lines. It doesn't avoid reading them, though, because that's impossible :) The only problem against a more low-level approach is that I expect it would allocate unnecessary strings (and collect them at first notice) - but then again, writing low-allocation string processing in .NET is rather tricky.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not your case, but if you knew the length of each line you would calculate the start index byte of the line you look for and could go like below:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("fullFileName");

fs.Seek(startByte, SeekOrigin.Current)
for (long offset = startByte; offset < fs.Length; offset++)
{
     fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);
     char value = (char)((byte)fs.ReadByte());
    .
    .
    .
//To determine the end of each line you can use the conditions below
     if (value == 0xA)//  hex \n
     {
          if (offset == fs.Length)
              continue;

     }
     else if (value == 0xD)// hex \r
     {
         if (offset == fs.Length - 1)
              continue;
     }

}
```